# launch app on usb device connection on android

Tags: android

I've got 2 devices mk802(android device) and ACS122(rfid card reader). I'd like to develop small application that will do the stuff, but at first I'd like to ask if it is possible to automatically start application when I plug the reader to mk802.

I can see in documentation to usbmanager there is ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED. So can I crate some listener (intent?) which will recognize the device (ACS122) and if it is this, it will start my application?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your Android device supports it you might be able to do this without writing any code as there is an app made my Sony that was designed for their devices but is available on Google Play, called [liveware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware). It may only run on ICS at the latest version but if you can find the older liveware versions it should run on devices as far back as 2.3.

When a device is attached it will prompt you to select an application to start when the device is attached in the future.

You can also write the code, as per your original thought above. This is demonstrated quite well in the example usb program "launcher" that comes with APIs from level 12 onwards.

You may struggle with the "ACCESSORY" intent because only accessories that comply with the Android USB accessory extensions are detected, I believe. That said, if you are actually operating in host mode then then intent to look for is "ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" and this is more likely to work for you in my experience.